# How to add padding to drop down menus in contact form 7?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm trying to add a 15px padding to my drop down menus in contact form 7. How can I do that?

I already tried to add some custom CSS code (see my code below), and it doesn't seem to be working correctly. But as soon as I inspect the page to find the problem, the padding is suddenly working! What is going on? Thanks for the help!

(I tried clearing my cache everywhere I possibly could, but it didn't solve the problem.)

```
<p class="secteur-form">
<label class="titre-champ">Choisir un secteur<span class="asterix">*</span><br><em class="obligatoire">Obligatoire</em>
[select* secteur include_blank "Sainte-Foy" "Beauport" "Lebourgneuf"]
</label>
</p>

<p class="mois-form">
<label class="titre-champ">Mois d'occupation désiré<span class="asterix">*</span><br><em class="obligatoire">Obligatoire</em>
[select* mois include_blank "Janvier" "Février" "Mars" "Avril" "Mai" "Juin" "Juillet" "Août" "Septembre" "Octobre" "Novembre" "Décembre"]
</label>
</p>
```

```
.wpcf7-form select{
padding: 15px !important;
}
```

This is what I see live on the website:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2myff.jpg

And this is what I see when I inspect the page:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYD0Q.jpg

Comment: Try clearing cache if you have any caching plugin

Comment: Have you tried a [hard refresh](https://www.getfilecloud.com/blog/2015/03/tech-tip-how-to-do-hard-refresh-in-browsers/#.XLCqcOhKiUk) to force your browser to re-download your stylesheet?

Comment: Yes, I cleared my cache everywhere I possibly could. I even disabled my caching plugin to see if that was the problem. But it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Most probably another css style overrides the current one.

Comment: Check if other css overrides your style. if yes, improve the specificity of your selector by adding ID or classes.

Comment: The weird thing is that when I try to inspect the dropdown menus (to see what CSS is overriding it), the 15px padding is suddenly applied to my dropdown menus ! I can see my custom CSS working properly (see the images I linked to the post). But as soon as I close the dev tools panel, the padding is not working anymore. So I have no way of finding out which CSS causes this to happen...

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Typically, the class `wpcf7-form-control` is what is used to wrap each select, text field, etc.

```
    span.wpcf7-form-control-wrap select.wpcf7-form-control {
         padding: 15px;
    }
```

Comment: I tried and it still didn't work :( but thanks for the help

Comment: did you try adding !important to what I put?

Comment: Yes I did, but still not working :( even when I clear my cache and try it in an incognito window...

Comment: What is the url for this page?

Comment: At the very least, you need to show more of the inspect element screen.

Comment: How weird ! I guess it was a caching problem after all... But I tried to clear my cache everywhere (server's cache, plugin's cache, the cache of the site, even deleted the cache from Chrome but nothing worked). Well, the important is that it's working now so thanks a lot for your help! :)

Comment: You could probably use my answer without the important.